# Loop in nested json array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Sample of json string that receive by post is here:

```
[
  {
    "gc": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "ti": "title1",
        "oid": 1,
        "mid": "1-2",
        "mc": 2,
        "gct": 1,
        "ma": 1,
        "isu": 0
      }
    ],
    "gcm": [
      {
        "mid": "11",
        "gcid":"1",
        "sid": 58,
        "msg": "msg1 ",
        "sdt": "2018-11-12T13:58:24.627",
        "ma": 20181112135822,
        "isu": 0
      },
      {
        "mid": "12",
        "gcid":"1",
        "sid": 58,
        "msg": "msg2 ",
        "sdt": "2018-11-12T13:58:24.627",
        "ma": 20181112135822,
        "isu": 0
      }
    ],
    "gcms": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "11"
      },
      {
        "id": "112",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "11"
      },
      {
        "id": "121",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "12"
      },
      {
        "id": "122",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "12"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I use below code to loop in decoded array but only loop 1 time in array:

```
$json  = json_decode($input, true);
foreach ($json as $value) {
    $this->logger->info("Start update_new_data ->");
    if (isset($value['gc'])) {
        $this->logger->info("gc key exist");
        foreach ($value["gc"] as $jObj) {
        }
    } else {
        if (isset($value['gcm'])) {
            $this->logger->info("gcm key exist");
            foreach ($value["gcm"] as $jObj) {
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($value['gcms'])) {
                $this->logger->info("gcms key exist");
                foreach ($value["gcms"] as $jObj) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->logger->info("End update_new_data ->");
}
```

I want loop in array, if key is 'gc' loop in 'gc' array and loop again and if key is 'gcm' loop in 'gcm' array and if key is 'gcms' loop in 'gcms' array. I have to check the key because key mybe not exist in json string.
Test many code but can't solve problem.
How can i do this?

Comment: you can use `if ..elseif...elseif...else` or `array_keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mohammadi This Can work for you.

```
$json  = json_decode($input, true);
$json = isset($json[0])?$json[0]:'';
$this->logger->info("Start update_new_data ->");
if(!empty($json)){
foreach ($json as $Key=>$value) {
if(isset($Key)){
if ($Key == "gc") {
    $this->logger->info("gc key exist");
    foreach ($value as $jObj) {
    }
} 
else if ($Key == "gcm") {
    $this->logger->info("gcm key exist");
    foreach ($value as $jObj) {
    }
}
else if ($Key == "gcms") {
     $this->logger->info("gcms key exist");
     foreach ($value as $jObj) {
     }
}
}
$this->logger->info("End update_new_data ->");
}
}
```

you can use this "$json = isset($json[0])?$json[0]:'';"line if you do not want to change the json structure because of the whole json date(array) inside a single array so you can get the first index of the array. if you change the json like this (shown below) then you did not require this                      "$json = isset($json[0])?$json[0]:'';"

```
$input = '{  
    "gc": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "ti": "title1",
        "oid": 1,
        "mid": "1-2",
        "mc": 2,
        "gct": 1,
        "ma": 1,
        "isu": 0
      }
    ],
    "gcm": [
      {
        "mid": "11",
        "gcid":"1",
        "sid": 58,
        "msg": "msg1 ",
        "sdt": "2018-11-12T13:58:24.627",
        "ma": 20181112135822,
        "isu": 0
      },
      {
        "mid": "12",
        "gcid":"1",
        "sid": 58,
        "msg": "msg2 ",
        "sdt": "2018-11-12T13:58:24.627",
        "ma": 20181112135822,
        "isu": 0
      }
    ],
    "gcms": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "11"
      },
      {
        "id": "112",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "11"
      },
      {
        "id": "121",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "12"
      },
      {
        "id": "122",
        "ma": 1,
        "mid": 58,
        "sdt": "1",
        "isu": 0,
        "msf": 0,
        "gcid": "1",
        "cmid": "12"
      }
    ]
  }';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for iteration:

```
$json  = json_decode($input, true);
$json_keys = array_keys($json);
foreach ($json_keys as $json_key) {
    $item = $json[$json_key];
    foreach ($item as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $subrow) {
            echo isset($subrow['id']) ? $subrow['id'] : 'nope';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I use this, but can't get $row values in foreach, `$id = $row['id'];`

Comment: `gc` is array too, so you can't get $row['id'] value. I changed code example to your needs

Answer (score 0):

As per the json given in the question, the decoded array has single element which encloses all the elements. In that case, instead of looping through `$json`  like: `foreach ($json..`, try looping through `$json[0]` like: `foreach ($json[0]...` And to get the key, you don't have to use array_keys, just run the loop with key like: `foreach ($json[0] as $key => $value)...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use a loop for the outer array. Simply access the parts you want directly:

```
$json  = json_decode($input, true);
$value = $json[0];
$this->logger->info("Start update_new_data ->");
if (isset($value['gc'])) {
    $this->logger->info("gc key exist");
    foreach ($value["gc"] as $jObj) {
    }
} 
if (isset($value['gcm'])) {
    $this->logger->info("gcm key exist");
    foreach ($value["gcm"] as $jObj) {
    }
}
if (isset($value['gcms'])) {
     $this->logger->info("gcms key exist");
     foreach ($value["gcms"] as $jObj) {
     }
}
$this->logger->info("End update_new_data ->");
```

This way you see your json structure more clearly (array inside an array).

Comment: I have to loop in array